# Передать [switch] внутри Start-Job

Tags: powershell

Есть скрипт для логона пользователей, вызывает по очереди другие скрипты, в зависимости от условий.
Для того, что бы вызывать скрипты можно было по отдельности вручную, добавлен параметр [switch]$Silent. Вопрос - как передать данный параметр внутри Start-Job? Пробовал по-разному добавлять в argumentlist - значение всегда попадает в соседний параметр, независимо от очередности.
Пример основного скрипта

```
Param(
    [string]$location = 'C:\Users',
    [switch]$Silent
)
    Start-Job -FilePath ".\Fonts_Install.ps1" -ArgumentList ($Silent,$location) | Wait-Job
```

Вырезка из вызываемого скрипта

```
Param(
    [switch]$Silent = $false,
    [string]$location = '.'
)

switch ($Silent) {
    $false {
        if ($Error.Count -gt 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i -le ($Error.Items.Count + 1); $i++) {
                $errMSG = "$Error"
            }
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$errMSG", "Error", "OK", "Error")
        }
        else {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("ок", "Fonts", "OK", "Asterisk") | out-null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, **указание сквозных аргументов через [`Start-Job`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) `-ArgumentList` ( `-Args`) ограничен *позиционными* аргументами**, что **предотвращает привязку параметров `[switch]`**, чьи аргументы по определению должны быть *именованными*.

В качестве обходного пути вместо использования `-FilePath` вызовите свой сценарий через параметр `-ScriptBlock`. Внутри *скриптового блока* (`{ ... }` именованные аргументы могут использоваться в вызовах скрипта, как обычно:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  .\Fonts_Install.ps1 -Silent:$using:Silent $using:Location
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

- Обратите внимание на использование области `$using:` для встраивания значений переменных из области действия вызывающей программы в блок сценария, который будет выполняться в фоновом режиме.
- Вам по-прежнему нужно обращаться к параметру `-Silent` *по имени*, а о том, включен переключатель или нет, можно сообщить, добавив к нему `:$true` или `:$false`, что и означает `:$using:Silent`.

P.S. Ответ получен тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963472/pass-switch-inside-start-job/72967196#72967196